# Protractor: Browser is restarted automatically if 'shardTestFiles': true

Tags: protractor

I have a lot of specs files.
I run them in one browser instanse ('shardTestFiles': false) and DO NOT restart Browser between tests.
So tests are going smoothly and everything is OK.

But I want to run tests in several Browser instances:
so I set
'shardTestFiles': true
and
'maxInstances': 4.
And now Browser is restarted automatically after each spec file, even when
restartBrowserBetweenTests: false.
So it dramatically slows down my tests.

Is it possible not to restart Browser after each spec file?

Comment: More context is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the same, and I found this github thread:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4550
In short: it is not possible currently, but a feature for custom schedulers is on its way. With the scheduler you should be able to handle that.